# Difficulty extracting stock tickers - pd.read_html not preserving whitespace

Tags: python, html, pandas, stock

I'm trying to get stock tickers from a few hundred ETF's from etfdailynews.com. I started by getting a list of category names from https://etfdailynews.com/etfs/, then concatenating the category to that url to open a page with the ETF names and symbols. For example, https://etfdailynews.com/etfs/technology-equities-etfs/

On the page, the title "Fund Symbol/Name" has the symbol, then name beneath. The plan was to read the table, then assuming there was some \n between the symbol and name, split to get just the symbol. For example, getting the first 10:

```
sector_table = pd.read_html("https://etfdailynews.com/etfs/Large-Cap-Blend-ETFs")
etf_list = list(sector[0]["Fund Symbol/Name"].iloc[0:10])
```

The problem is that it is returning the names and the symbols without any whitespace between. Since some symbols are sometimes 3 and other times 4 characters long I can't perform a simple splice. An example of the list returned above:

> ['SPYSPDR S&P 500',  'IVViShares Core S&P 500 ETF',  'VTIVanguard
>   Total Stock Market ETF',  'VOOVanguard S&P 500 ETF',  'VIGVanguard Div
>   Appreciation ETF - DNQ',  'IWBiShares Russell 1000 ETF', 
>   'RSPGuggenheim S&P 500 Equal Weight ETF',  'USMViShares Edge MSCI Min
>   Vol USA ETF',  'ITOTiShares Core S&P Total U.S. Stock Market ETF', 
>   'SCHXSchwab U.S. Large-Cap ETF']

Perhaps there is a way to do as I want with beautifulsoup, but I am not proficient with that module, and from what I know pd.read_html is better at working with tables but I could be entirely mistaken.

EDIT: I should clarify that I plan to open the URL of the ETF's to extract the tickers. I had planned to concatenate the ETF symbols to the URL. An alternative that allows me to simply extract the URL's of the ETF's works perfectly as well.

Comment: Working on a BeautifulSoup function

Answer (score 0):

The function parses the cell below on the line break by adding a semi-colon to the 
 tag and splitting the text.

[image: TD Cell with Line Break]

(HTML as of 3/18/18 https://etfdailynews.com/etfs/Large-Cap-Blend-ETFs/)

`html 
<td class="bold"><a class="show" href="/etf/SPY/">SPY<br/>
                    <span class="thirteen unbold">SPDR S&amp;P 500</span></a></td>`

After you have opened the url with urllib or requests, pass the html table to the function below and it will return a DataFrame.

```
def parse_etf_html(data_table, debug=False):



    header = [th.text for th in data_table.findAll('th')]

    # header modifications
    compound_field = header.pop(0)

    header.insert(0, compound_field.split('/')[0])
    header.insert(1, 'Fund ' + compound_field.split('/')[1])

    compound_field = header.pop(8)
    header.insert(8, compound_field + '_cur')
    header.insert(9, compound_field + '_per')


    # Row 0 is the table header

    extracted_data = list()

    # Starting at row 1, loop each table row 

    for tr in data_table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        extracted_row = list()

        if debug:
            # simple test to verify if number of items matches expectations.
            row_parsing_log = dict()

        for td in tr.findAll('td'):

            #<td class="bold"><a class="show" href="/etf/SPY/">SPY<br/><span class="thirteen unbold">SPDR S&amp;P 500</span></a></td>,
            if td.find('a') and td.find('br') and td.find('span'):
                td.br.string=";"
                extracted_row.extend(td.text.split(";"))

                if debug:
                    row_parsing_log['symbol_fund_as_expected'] = len(td.text.split(";")) == 2

            # <td class="grade-4">+0.25<br/>(0.09%)</td>
            elif td.find('br') and [td.find('strong'),td.find('small'), td.find('a')]  == [None, None, None]:
                td.br.string=";"
                # percent change is enclosed with ().  remove to avoid confusion 
                extracted_row.append(td.text.split(";")[0])
                extracted_row.append(td.text.split(";")[1].replace("(", "").replace(")", ""))

                if debug:
                    row_parsing_log['day_chg_as_expected'] = len(td.text.split(";")) == 2

            #<td class="text-center grade-1"> <strong>A</strong><br/> <small>Strong Buy</small> </td>
            elif td.find('br') and td.find('strong') and td.find('small'):
                # Appears to be parsed correctly by pandas read html
                extracted_row.append(td.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

            else:
                extracted_row.append(td.text)


        record = dict(zip(header, extracted_row))

        if debug:
            record.update(row_parsing_log)

        # append each row
        extracted_data.append(record)


    if debug:
        header.extend(['symbol_fund_as_expected', 'day_chg_as_expected'])

    outputDF = pd.DataFrame(extracted_data)[header]

    # data types


    return outputDF
```

Link to static notebook:
https://github.com/emican86/49350586/blob/master/read_etf_html_tables.ipynb

Link to Azure notebook ( you can clone and use as a live demo): 
https://notebooks.azure.com/emican86/libraries/read-etf-html-tables